# Android ORMLite: one object but two tables

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

So I have created a general class called `Food`.

One of the FoodStuff I have are sweets so I have created a databaseTable called 'sweets' where 3 properties of the class are stored within class, namely, `foodname, id and sugar levels` of the sweets.

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "sweets")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Food implements Serializable {

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    @JsonProperty
    private String id; //for both sweets and meats
    @DatabaseField
    @JsonProperty
    private String foodname; //for both sweets and meats
    @DatabaseField
    @JsonProperty
    public int sugar; //for sweets only
    @DatabaseField
    @JsonProperty
    public int protein;  //for meats only
```

Now lets say I want to expand my android app by adding an extra tab at the top next to the 'sweets' tab which would display all foodstuff containing meats.

I want to add in an additional databaseTable into my sqlite database called `meats` and it should store only the `foodname, id and protein levels.`

Is this even possible using one class in ORMLite? I thought maybe it would look something like this but this doesn't work as it confuses ORMLite as to which table it should import the data into:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "sweets")
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "meats")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Food implements Serializable {

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    @JsonProperty
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty
    private String foodname;
    @JsonProperty
    public int sugar;
    @JsonProperty
    public int protein;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this even possible using one class in ORMLite? I thought maybe it would look something like this but this doesn't work as it confuses ORMLite as to which table it should import the data into:

I would consider using a subclass.  So you would make `Food` be `abstract` and then have:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "sweets")
public class Sweets extends Food {
```

and

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "meats")
public class Meats extends Food {
```

If you must use the same class then you can [configure the tables programmatically](http://ormlite.com/docs/class-config).